# Make entire html page disable/unselectable except one textbox and button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to make entire page disable/unselectable except one textbox and button. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what you did yet. Do add your code.

Comment: I am not getting any idea. Can you give me some hint so that I can try it.

Comment: ok, let me build something that will help you.

Comment: Ok. you can give me some idea also so that I can try.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
*:not([type='textbox']):not(button){
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;    
    user-select: none;    
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *